# Docker not logging into local repository

Tags: docker, repository, local, nexus

I have just set up a local VM running Nexus. I have configured a Docker repository on port 5000. I have a separate VM running Docker. I have configured the repository in /etc/docker/daemon.json as so:

```
{
  "insecure-registries": ["192.168.0.5:5000", "nexus:5000"]
}
```

I then restarted the Docker service. and I have run the command:

```
docker login 192.168.0.5:5000
```

I am prompted for a username and password, and when I enter them it returns with::

```
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: unauthorized: incorrect username or password
```

I have checked the Docker documentation, and other online resources on how to login to a local docker repository, but I have exactly the same configuration and it just always throws this error.

If I try to push my image, it attempts to contact the local repository, but it complains there are no credentials (as well it should):

```
[root@docker repo]$ docker tag repo 192.168.0.5:5000/repo
[root@docker repo]$ docker image push 192.168.0.5:5000/repo
Using default tag: latest
The push refers to repository [192.168.0.5:5000/repo]
7d5760c4aa8d: Preparing
3102e53269f4: Preparing
2f140462f3bc: Preparing
63c99163f472: Preparing
ccdbb80308cc: Preparing
no basic auth credentials
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: The login command and error message do not match each other (the error message indicates you did not include a registry ip/port in the command). I would double check that is the command you ran.

Comment: Hi - Welcome to my problem. Even though I specified the IP and port, it complains it couldn't login to https://registry-1.docker.io. Why is it doing that?! Looks like a bug to me, but I don't know enough to be certain

Comment: For me, it doesn't do that, it looks like you are running `docker login` without an IP/port argument. What version of docker is this, and have you verified that's the error you see with the IP/port included (don't run the command from a script, run it directly on the CLI with that argument)?

Comment: We aren't going to get anywhere if you keep doubting what I am saying. However, one last time. Here is the command I am running (in fact I ran it just now): `docker login 192.168.0.5:5000` and here is the response: `Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: unauthorized: incorrect username or password`

Comment: Did that command prompt you for a user and password?

Comment: Sorry, yes it did. I input my admin user credentials then it threw the error. Strangely, I have just cloned the exact same template I used for this VM into another one and installed Docker in the exact same way, but this time it logged into my Nexus repository fine...

Comment: Wait! It's happening on this VM now:
`[root@docker2 ~]$ docker login 192.168.0.5:5000
Username: admin
Password:
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: unauthorized: incorrect username or password`

This time it happened after adding pass as a key store. I added `{ "credsStore": "pass" }` to $HOME/.docker/config.json and restarted docker, then logged out and back in again to my repository

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233783/discussion-between-tom-moore-and-bmitch).

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same but only with MacOS "Docker Desktop" installations. On Windows it's working as expected.

```
Client:
 Cloud integration: 1.0.17
 Version:           20.10.8
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.16.6
 Git commit:        3967b7d
 Built:             Fri Jul 30 19:55:20 2021
 OS/Arch:           darwin/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.8
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.16.6
  Git commit:       75249d8
  Built:            Fri Jul 30 19:52:31 2021
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.4.9
  GitCommit:        e25210fe30a0a703442421b0f60afac609f950a3
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.1
  GitCommit:        v1.0.1-0-g4144b63
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

As I am trying to login to a local registry (using Artifactory) I've checked the reverse proxy's logs. The MacOS client doesn't even try to reach the local registry.

I fixed it by updating Docker Desktop from 4.1.0 to 4.1.1. Seems like an undocumented bugfix to me.

Comment: Fixed by updating Docker Desktop from 4.1.0 to 4.1.1. Seems like an undocumented bugfix to me.